# Font rendering differently in Opera 9

Tags: css, opera

The font is rendering as a serif in Opera 9, image here in case you're curious and don't have Opera 9:
[image](http://moreheadplanetarium.org/redesign/troubleshooting/opera9.jpg)

I've looked around but can't seem to find why Opera 9 wouldn't listen to the CSS for font-family: Helvetica.  Any ideas?

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a font problem in Opera 9 under linux.

See [this post](http://ifacethoughts.net/2007/09/02/smooth-fonts-for-opera-in-linux/) about the problem.

Comment: I figured it out, my font-family had to be written Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif in order to Opera 9 to render correctly.  I don't think our users run linux, but I'll check out the post just in case :)

Comment: Providing more than one font family is always best pratice, in case that a client cannot render the first font it will choose the second and so on. If you put them in order of "similarity" to the font you intended to use, you'll get a "graceful degradation" insteadd of displaying a totally wrong font.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in Opera 10.01. Don't support old versions of Opera. Seriously.

Comment: I would like to, but Opera 9 is in the top 10 browsers that our users use, they're not very up to date in the other browsers all around...

Comment: I agree with you about older version of Opera, but that doesn't answer the question about Helvetica :P

Comment: Wrong. Opera 10's useragent says "9.8", so your results are biased. You probably have way more Opera 10 users than you know.

Comment: It's obviously a browser problem if it breaks in Opera 9 but not Opera 10. You don't program around the broken unless the broken is IE.

Comment: I just refuse to believe that Opera 9 users make the majority of any top-10 browsers for any site. Anywhere.

Comment: okay, good to know, our analytics just says version "9" I should probably check out some better analytics to get a better picture.

Comment: @Stefan : IN SOVIET RUSSIA http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Mail.ru_.28Russia.2C_2009_to_present.29

Comment: @Felipe: I refuse to believe it, and yet the numbers are right there. I...I...*explodes*

Comment: Sure, but I never thought that Opera was big anywhere. Whenever I say I use Opera, people ask if I mean "that wii browser".